# this.router.navigate not detecting any change on safari

Tags: angular

i am trying to open dashboard when server return true for login call, but when user enter email, password and press login it send call on server get response but stuck on same login screen, it's working fine on chrome but not working  on IOS chrome and safari

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/dashboard';
}

doLogin() {
    console.log("Before server call");
    this.authService.doLogin(this.account.email, this.account.password).subscribe(
        response => {
              console.log("Server return response");
            if (response.success) {
                console.log("Before Navigate"+response.success);
                try{
                  this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
                }catch(e){
                    console.log("catch block"+e);
                }
                  console.log("after Navigate");
            }
            else {
                console.log("success false"+response.message);
                this.messageService.showMessage('INVALID CREDENTIALS', null);
            }
        },
        error => {
            console.log("Error");
            this.messageService.showMessage('INVALID CREDENTIALS', null);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: i checked logs and they are
Before server call
Server return response
Before Navigate
after Navigate

Comment: `router.navigate` is asynchronous, `try/catch` is meaningless in that case

Comment: Oh yes, actually i was trying to catch issue that is happening here